# Map browser tabs to cmd+tab-able programs

Tags: google-chrome, dock, tabs

I notice that running Slack / Spotify / Whatsapp etc as tabs in Chrome needs a lot less resources than running them separately in their own native Electron apps.

But when running them as tabs, what I miss is the ability to cmd+tab directly to them, instead of go to Chrome and then select the right tab.

Is there a tool to make this possible? It would have to map a tab to something running in the dock to make that possible I guess.

Comment: I'm on a mac of course (I did mention the Dock). My keyboard says alt instead of cmd because it is an external one, so its just an old habit to call it that, been working previously with Windows for years.

Comment: OK. If you always keep them in the same positions you can get there in 2 moves, not one. Ctrl/number to the correct Space, then Cmd/number to the correct tab. Won't work if you use fullscreen, though.